# Use a custom filename in quantmod saveChart function

Tags: r, quantmod

In R `quantmod`, when use `saveChart` to save the plot ,how to assign file name for the result ?

Below code `saveChart('my_plot.png', width=13)` can't work

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
chartSeries(AAPL)
require(TTR)
addBBands()
saveChart('my_plot.png', width=13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*saveChart* gets the filename from object name. Here are alternatives to get the custom filename:

Set auto assign to FALSE, and name the data as you wish before plotting:

```
my_plot <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE)
chartSeries(my_plot)
addBBands()
saveChart(.type = "png")
```

Use auto assign, then re-assign it to other object before plotting:

```
getSymbols("AAPL")
my_plot <- AAPL
chartSeries(my_plot)
addBBands()
saveChart(.type = "png")
```

Use png graphics device:

```
png("my_plot.png")
chartSeries(AAPL)
addBBands()
dev.off()
```